# ¿Cómo cerrar la hebra inicial de una conexión a AS400?

Tags: vb, as400

Les comento mi situación; después de haber cerrado mi conexión(desde VB), en el servidor AS400 la sesión que se creo por la conexión queda con un estatus TIMW (Espera a que finalice un tiempo para cerrar la hebra inicial) yo quiero cerrar esa hebra, me han dicho que use "SIGNOFF" desde mi aplicación, lo he intentado pero no funciona.

Esta es la función para cerrar esa hebra inicial:

```
Public Sub myfunction()
Dim finhilo As String = "SIGNOFF"
ExecuteNonQuery(finhilo) ''Esta es una función que ejecuta un comando IDB2COMMAND 
End Sub
```

Esta es la Excepción:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Error al crear el formulario.
> Consulte Exception.InnerException para obtener más detalles. Error:
> SQL0104 Símbolo SIGNOFF no válido. Símbolos válidos: ( CL END GET SET
> CALL DROP FREE HOLD LOCK OPEN WITH ALTER.'
> Excepción Interna:
> iDB2SQLErrorException:
> SQL0104 Símbolo SIGNOFF no válido. Símbolos válidos: ( CL END GET SET
> CALL DROP FREE HOLD LOCK OPEN WITH ALTER.

Podría alguien indicarme de que manera lo puedo hacer.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.